# Delete all and then save objects in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

In my application, I fetch some data from an API and save it to Core Data.

Then, I want to be able to update my data by fetching the new ones and once the fetch is successful (no connection error) I want to replace the core data objects with the new ones. But when I try to do it I have conflict error…

Here is my code:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

// Try to fetch new data via API request
SDK.fetchData { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let items):
        // items are already NSManagedObjects decoded from a JSON
        // Delete all data
        let fetchRequest = Item.fetchRequest()
        let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        // Save new data
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error) // Here I get a conflict error
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        // There has been an error, keep the old data
        print(error)
    }
}
```

For more clarity, here is the `Item` class:

```
import CoreData

@objc(Item)
class Item: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
    }

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                fatalError("Failed to decode Item")
        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Any idea on how it's possible to achieve this without having any conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code the new items are inserted and later **all** items are deleted with uncommitted changes.

A better workflow is

- Fetch all items into a temporary variable.
- Get the new items from the API.
- On success commit the changes (save the context).
- Delete the temporarily fetched items keeping the new ones.
- Save the context again.